# Meteor integration with node-ffi on client-side

Tags: meteor, node-ffi

Can I use Meteor with node-ffi (https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) on client-side to allow users to load a native shared library on browser, making the browser capable of running the library and return the result to the server?
In practice: the user access the site from browser, click somewere, loads the library library path, them the library is executed and returns the result to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this won't work. The browser won't support what you are doing, as its a server wrapper, and will build an architecture specific wrapper to run the c++ code.